# How to get the List<Lead> from List<LeadShare> in apex

Tags: apex, leads, apex-sharing

`Map<String, List<LeadShare>> UserLeadShareMapVal = new Map<String, List<LeadShare>>();`

How to convert the above Map to

`Map<String, List<Lead>> UserLeadMapVal`

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include the work you have done so far and where you are stuck.  Have you looked at the [`Leadshare` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_leadshare.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you say `LeadShare` you already have this record with you.

Technically you can just iterate through Map and get the keys and values from it.

```
Map<String, List<LeadShare>> UserLeadShareMapVal = new Map<String, List<LeadShare>>();

Map<String,List<Lead>> UserLeadMapVal = new Map<String, List<Lead>>();

for(String eachKey : UserLeadShareMapVal.keySet()){
    List<LeadShare> leadShares = UserLeadShareMapVal.get(eachKey);
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
    for(LeadShare leadShare : leadShares){
        leads.add(new Lead(Id=leadShare.LeadId));
    }
    UserLeadMapVal.put(eachKey,leads);
}
```

Finally your `UserLeadMapVal` will have `Map<String,List<Lead>>`

**NOTE** Lead in `UserLeadMapVal` only has Id. It does not hold any Lead related data apart from Id.

Comment: How to get all the other lead data apart from only ID?

Comment: You need to go for query with the Lead ids